# Multaply.com - right click on the website is not working

Tags: mobile

My new website: [www.multaply.com](http://www.multaply.com). I am unable to do right click on it. Would it be because the developer might have blocked with some plugin? Your help will be much appreciated. Website is being built using WordPress CMS, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript to prevent this at Line 81 to 90.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mousedwn(e) { 
try { if (event.button == 2||event.button == 3) return false; }  
catch (e) { if (e.which == 3) return false; }

}
    document.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; }
    document.ondragstart   = function() { return false; }
    document.onmousedown   = mousedwn;
    </script>
```

The **event.button == 2** is your Right-Click. Just remove it...

Answer (score 0):

The developer has installed the plugin "WP Content Copy Protection" on the site which includes some javascript that disables right click and various copy functions. You need to uninstall this plugin to re-enable right click.